# How to check if a zip file is corrupted using .net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I want to check if a zip file is corrupted before decompress it. If a corrupted zip file is opened manually ,it throws a error. How can it be done in c# so that if a zip is corrupted,an exception will be thrown.

P.s it is possible in .net 4.5. But I need it in 3.5

Thanks

Comment: You can use CRC32 check. But you must have corrupted and uncorrupted zip files CRC32. So you can compare them easily.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I won't have an uncorrupted file to compare...I need to check whether any given zip file is corrupted or not

Answer (score 4):

[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/), a free open source library for handling zip files in .NET languages, supports a [CheckZip()](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DotNetZipHelp/html/910d0ca1-a0ce-0b86-1459-1b13dd1f30d8.htm) method that does what you want. There are various levels of assurance available at your option. The basic level just checks consistency of metadata. The most complete level does a full extraction of the zip file into a bitbucket to verify that the actual compressed data is not corrupted.

**Update :**

[Section 4.3.7 of this page](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) says that the compressed size is 4 bytes starting from byte 18. You could try reading that and comparing it to the size to the file.

However, I think it's pretty much useless for checking if the zip file is corrupted for two reasons:

1. Some zip files contain more bytes than just the zip part. For
   example, [self-extracting archives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-extracting_archives) have an executable part yet
   they're still valid zip.
2. The file can be corrupted without changing its size. So, I suggest
   calculating the `CRC` for a guaranteed method of checking for
   corruption.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...well, I need a logic like performing an action on the zip file should throw an exception if it is corrupted...like I mentioned while opening manually it throws an error...some logic to replicate such behavior is what I want...

Comment: Your welcome, i updated my answer, check it please :)